# Unit test with native query using @Modifying doesn't work in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I have two native queries (select and delete) in my repository and i call these methods in my service class.I want to write a unit test but my two native queries does not work

Entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity(name = "Products")
public class Products {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;
    
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime delivery;

 }
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {
    

    @Query(value = "SELECT count(p) FROM product p WHERE p.id = :id and (p.created BETWEEN :start AND :end) ", nativeQuery = true)
    int countDeliveryProduct(@Param("id")Long Id, @Param("start")ZonedDateTime start, @Param("end")ZonedDateTime end);
    

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM product p WHERE p.id = :id and (p.created BETWEEN :start AND :end) ", nativeQuery = true)
    int deleteByIdAndDeliveryDate(@Param("id")Long Id, @Param("start")ZonedDateTime start, @Param("end")ZonedDateTime end);
   

}
```

my service class

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    private ProductRepository prod;

    public Long allProducts(long id, ZonedDateTime start, ZonedDateTime end) 
    {
      return Long.valueof(prod.countDeliveryProduct(id,start,end));
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public Long deleteProducts(long id, ZonedDateTime start, ZonedDateTime end) 
    {
      return Long.valueof(prod.deleteByIdAndDeliveryDate(id,start,end));
    }

 }
```

My unit test method

```
@Test
  @Transactional
  void myUnitTest() {

    // GIVEN
    var product=new Product(1,"Code1",LocalDateTime.now(), ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-12-13T12:30:00.987+02:00");
    var result = productRepository .save(product);

    var allProducts = productRepository.countDeliveryProduct(1,ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-12-01T12:30:00.987+02:00"),ZonedDateTime.parse("2099-12-31T12:30:00.987+02:00"));

    // WHEN
    var numberDeletedProduct = productRepository.deleteByIdAndDeliveryDate(1,ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-12-01T12:30:00.987+02:00"),ZonedDateTime.parse("2099-12-31T12:30:00.987+02:00"));

    // THEN
    Assertions.assertEquals(numberDeletedProduct, 1);
  }
```

When i run my unit test, allProducts equals 0 instead of 1 and numberDeletedProduct equals 0 instead of 1 and my test failed.

How can i fix that ? I doesn't see the problem because LocalDateTime.now is between ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-12-01T12:30:00.987+02:00") and ZonedDateTime.parse("2099-12-31T12:30:00.987+02:00"). The problem is in the conversion date . My zonedDateTime is Europe/fr

Comment: Can you show full test class ?